# Error in installing .apk to android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

i am trying to install my .apk file to emulator but it is giving me error.

```
subh@subh:~/subh/droidbox/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools$ ./adb -s emulator-5554 install /home/subh/subh/androidapp/HelloAndroid/bin/HelloAndroid-release-unsigned.apk 
11 KB/s (2919 bytes in 0.245s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/HelloAndroid-release-unsigned.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

then i used jarsigner to sign the .apk

```
subh@subh:~/subh/androidapp/HelloAndroid/bin$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs HelloAndroid-release-unsigned.apk

  s = signature was verified 
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

no manifest.
jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)
subh@subh:~/subh/androidapp/HelloAndroid/bin$
```

but still i have problem of certificate.

Comment: do you have a certificate to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer .apk need to be signed before we want to release it.
In case of ant we have two modes debug and release.

```
# ant debug
```

this will automatically generate keypair and signed the .apk for us for the debug purpose.

```
#ant release
```

this will require to specify keystore in build.xml. 
for more details http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html
   http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

The second command seems to give an error. Can you try cleaning your project in Eclipse and creating a new APK?